# Creating cetificate without openssl

Tags: python, openssl

We are making the deploying script on Linux server, which will extract all the necessary components (tomcat server, port configuration....) for our web applications. At this moment, I am stuck with the PFX certificate generation for the Https connection. The deploying script is written by using Python. Is there anyone have experience with certification generation by using purely python without using OpenSSL or any of its wrappers? The reason that we dont want to use OpenSSL is there is a requirement that the deployed package should depend on the targeted machine as little as possible. And also, it does not need to be Python. Any language which is friendly to Linux Environment is ok (though Python is my favourite language)

Comment: Why isn't the puppetmaster generating the certs?

Comment: there are 2 options for the installation: either user uploads the certificate or the installer generates automatically. I still looking around to know how to validate the uploaded certificate for the first option (without using openssl, ofc)

Answer (score 2):

Can't help you with python but here's how you'd do it in PHP without openssl:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/tutorial.html#example1

Comment: thank you. Good to know about this, though php is definitely not my choice :( (+1 anyway :))